# Displaying backend response(zip file) content at frontend side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, frontend, zip

I made a axios request to the backend to get the zip file and I'm getting the right result... but not sure how to display the file content at frontend side.

This is the response from the backend.

[image]

this is the code for request to backend just a axios request.

```html
function handleSubmit(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      article['file'] = e.target.file.files[0];

      TransferService.makeRequest(article)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
      })
    }
```

Comment: Can you paste your code here... and your response too

Comment: Zipfiles have a compression mechanism, that no frontend tech can interprete, what you can do is to read the contents and return a response using axios that correctly maps the content...

Comment: I am using fastAPI as the backend tech, It is fine to send a single image but I want to display multiple images. How to send multiple images as a response? Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: Keep in mind that frontend is fone using javascript.. trying to read a zipfike using javascript is the issue... do everything the server that reads the zip file then return the desired  response to your application

Comment: try using DropZone, it's a perfect solution fir that... you could even cache the images while sending enabling you to send multiple images or a single image... or files   and also return the right results..